# JSX expressions must have one parent element nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs/reactjs to create this. I'm following a youtube video tutorial, in tutorial he does the same thing and it works for him but for me it doesn't work.

Any idea?

```js
const Index = (props) => {

  const {posts} = props;
  return(
    <div>
        {posts.map( post => (
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
          <p>{post.body}</p>
        ))
        }
    </div>
  )
}
Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const result = await data.json();

  return {
    posts: result
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't support returning multiple components so you need to wrap them inside a parent component. For this very purpose React provides `Fragment` or `<> </>` for shorthand syntax. Change your return statement to this and it'll work:

```
return(
    <div>
        {posts.map( post => (
          <>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </>
        ))
        }
    </div>
  )
```